# Powershell remove timestamp from filename

Tags: powershell

if I have some files with the name pippo_yyyymmdd.txt, pluto_yyyymmdd.txt etc etc, how can I remove the timestamp and rename the files as pippo.txt, pluto.txt ?

Answer (score 5):

Give this a try, it will remove any underscore followed by 8 digits. This is tha basicmidea, it doesn't take care of files end up having the same name:

```
Get-ChildItem *.txt | 
Where {$_.Name -match '_\d{8}\.txt' } | 
Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name -replace '_\d{8}'}
```

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same problem but unfortunately, PowerShell did not help me to solve it. So I then resorted to using Python to solve this problem and it worked like a bomb. You only need to copy the python script into the affected folder and run the script to remove the timestamp from all the files in the folder and subfolders.

```
import os, sys, re

fileNameList =[]
patho = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(sys.argv[0])) 

def renamer(fpath):
    for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(fpath):
        for name in files:
            if re.findall(r"(?ix)(\.ini)", name, re.I) == None:
                if re.search(r"(?ix)(\(\d{4}\_\d{2}_\d{2}\s\d{2}\_\d{2}\_\d{2}\sutc\))", name, re.I) != None:
                    old_name = os.path.join(path,name)
                    print(old_name)
                    new_name = re.sub(r"(?ix)(\s\(\d{4}\_\d{2}_\d{2}\s\d{2}\_\d{2}\_\d{2}\sutc\))", "", old_name, re.I)
                    print(new_name)
                    try:
                        os.replace(old_name,new_name)
                    except:
                        print(old_name)
                        fileNameList.append(old_name)

def log_errors_directories(fileNameList):
    filename = "Log of error filenames.txt"
    if len(fileNameList) != 0:
        log = open(filename, "a")
        log.write("###########################################################\n")
        i = 1
        for line in fileNameList:
            nr_line = str(i) + "  " + str(line)
            log.write(str(nr_line))
            log.write("\n")
            i += 1
        log.write("###########################################################\n\n")
        log.close()



renamer(patho)
log_errors_directories(fileNameList)
```

This is my first time posting code online. I hope it works for you as it did for me. :)